# Parse an Array of objects and populate table view cells Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, json, swift, mongodb

I have an app where I am trying to pull in data from an API which I created ( the API is based on ***NODE.js, MongoDB, Express.js*** )

Currently I am trying to pull and array of objects and then create a tableview based on that array of objects. For example if the Array of objects contains 4 objects, then the table view will have 4 cells. And on clicking a cell I will go to another view to where I will be able to view the detailed view of that object.

***How can I parse the returned JSON data from the API and populate the table view cells?***

**My Issue:**

Currently I am unable to parse the returned array of objects. Below is an image of the what the returned JSON contains:

[image]

**The Error:**

I am getting the following error:

```
Error could not parse JSON: Optional([
    {
       "_id": "55d1db984f80687875e43f89",
       "password": "$2a$08$OQB/r9iIZdSFlN9L5vaiE.qILB8gP/YtlsA3S41usVnM/eXHBW9j6",
       "email": "syed.kazmi26@gmail.com",
       "__v": 0,
       "sector": "Manufacturing",
       "jobTitle": "Something 1",
       "employeeName": "Something 1"
    },

   // it displays all the data being returned in JSON response

   ])
```

**Below is my SWIFT Code:**

```
  import UIKit

  class SectorViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBAction func getManufacturingBios(sender: AnyObject) {

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://myURL/user/all")!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    var err: NSError?

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Response: \(response)")

        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        println("Body: \(strData)")
        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

        // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
        if(err != nil) {

            println(err!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
            }

        else {

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.

            if let parseJSON = json {

            // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it

                var sector = parseJSON["sector"] as! String
                println("Succes: \(sector)")  

            }
            else {
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")

            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
}
```

Comment: It _looks_ like you're returning JSONP (ie the JSON is padded within a function called `Optional`). Does that sound right?

Comment: @Andy No I have no function called Optional within my code. Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try to use a NSArray instead of a Dictionary and change the reading options. I would recommend to do sth. like this:

```
var json : NSArray? = nil    
json = (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as? NSArray)!
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: oops didn't see your answer. Got 2 mins late.

Comment: @Tobias Thank you for the answer. Can you advise how to change the reading options?

Comment: Already changed that in my post, look close to the options parameter. I used MutableContainers as Reading Options. It specifies that arrays and dictionaries are created as mutable objects.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary
```

it should be

```
var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSArray
```

because your response content is an array starting with **[** and actually its elements are of type `NSDictionary`.
Always look for the starting braces if it is **[** or **{** .

**A JSON array starts & ends with square brackets and a JSON dictionary starts & ends with curly braces.**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After making your changes I got the following error " AnyObject is not convertible to String " on the following line           var sector = parseJSON["sector"] as! String

Comment: `json` is an array so you have to iterate through the array. If you need the first element then you should write `let firstDict= parseJSON[0] as NSDictionary`.